# In java is there any good way to replace part of a byte[] with a byte[] of different length?

Tags: java

I'm using airlift.joni, a new framework for regex.
The main function of this framework is change string to byte[] and then do regex match and similar works.
But since all elements are byte[], I can't use replace function in string and have to write my own replacement function.

I can get the start and end of the to-be-replaced pattern in a byte[] but don't know what's the proper way to replace it with a new byte[].

say we have a

```
byte[] A = new byte[10];
```

I want to replace A[2] to A[3] with a

```
byte[] B
```

whose length may not be 2.
Is there some good way to do this?
I only have the idea of creating a new array with length A.length+B.length-2 and copy every corresponding byte, but this will make the code too long.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: more descriptions added, but I think it won't help much...

Comment: So you are trying to insert `X` elements at some position in an array and shift the rest of the elements to the right after the `X` elements are inserted, huh?

Comment: Yes. Someone has given me the answer I want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why converting String to byte[]? String is composed of 2 byte chars, so for a 5 letter word, you'll have 10 bytes. I think it is more difficult to manipulate the letters this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to allocate a new array for the result and then use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
byte[] a = /*Allocated and initialized elsewhere*/;
byte[] b = /*Allocated and initialized elsewhere*/;
int replaceStart = 2; // inclusive
int replaceEnd = 4; // exclusive

byte[] c = new byte[a.length - (replaceEnd - replaceStart) + b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, replaceStart);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, replaceStart, b.length);
System.arraycopy(a, replaceEnd, c, replaceStart + b.length, a.length - replaceEnd);
```